# Inverse functions and their values?

Tags: calculus

I have these following questions and I managed to do about half of them, but the problem is that I am not confident in the correctness of them. Can someone help me with the ones that are incorrect or left blank?

Q: Suppose I have inverse functions $$f^{-1} = x^5 + 2x^3 + 3x + 1$$

**1.Compute $f(1)$ and $f^{-1}(1)$,**

My answer is

$f^{-1}(1) = 1^{5} + 2 + 3 + 1 = **7**$

$f(1) = ???$

**2.Compute the value of $x_{0}$ such that $f(x_{0}) = 1$**

My answer is

$x = y^{5} + 2x^{3} + 3y + 1$
$x = 7 = x_{0}$??

**3.Computer $y_{0}$ such that $f^{-1}(y_{0}) = 1$**

My answer ???

As you can see I'm not that good with these sort of questions, can someone guide me through the question mark ones and wrong ones?

Comment: I feel like I would do 3 before 1, because if you have an x such that $f^{-1}(x) = 1$, then $f(1) = x$. The reason is $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$. Also, a trivial example of when $f^{-1}(x) = 1$, is when $x = 0$.

Comment: BUt how do we find what x is?

Comment: We want $x^5 + 2x^3 + 3x + 1 = 1$, so $x(x^4 + 2x^2 + 3) = 0$. Notice that that term gives complex solutions if you use the quadratic formula, except for when $x = 0$. You can look at$ x^4 + 2x^2 + 3$ as $a^2 + 2a + 3$ where $a = x^2$.

Comment: Let me know if you understand. I'm going to go get some food. If you don't, I'll type up a detailed solution for you.

Comment: I got stuck at the part where you switched the x for a. WHat happened to x^4?

Comment: I'll type up a full answer. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the formula

$$ f^{-1}(x) = x^5 + 2x^3 + 3x + 1 $$ and we want to know when $f^{-1}(x) = 1$.

So we have,

$$ 1 = x^5 + 2x^3 + 3x + 1 \implies 0 = x(x^4 + 2x^2 + 3)$$

Notice that if we invent a variable $a$ that satisfies $a = x^2$ and sub $a $ into our equation, then we have

$$ 0 = (x^2)^2 + 2x^2 + 3 \implies 0 = a^2 + 2a + 3 $$.

Also notice that if we use the quadratic formula, the solutions for this equation are
$$a = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 2(1)(3)}}{2} $$.

But $4 - 2(1)(3) = -2$ and we can't take the square root of a negative number without going into the complex plane.

Thus, the only real solution to $0 = x(x^4 + 2x^2 + 3)$ is $x = 0$.

This answers question $3$, $ Y_0 = 0 $.

Now in question $1$, we need $f(1)$, but we know $f^{-1}(0) = 1$ and we know $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x $. Thus, $f(1) = f(f^{-1}(0)) = 0$.

Comment: I'd say you should more rightly say that $1=x^5+2x^+3x+1 \implies 0=x^4+2x^2+3 \mbox{ OR } x=0$, and since the first of the two has no real solutions then $x=0$ is the only one.

Comment: I see, and by the way. Are these steps applicable if lets say I INSTEAD given not the inverse, but the original one and asked to find what f^-1(1) was?

Comment: @ConMan Nice catch. I was typing a little too fast.

Comment: @user3718584 Yes. $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x $ as well.

Comment: FOr my number two, is it correct to just plug 1 into the ivnerse and get 7 for Xo?

Comment: @user3718584 Your two is right, but your work looks sloppy.

Comment: Ahh.. yeah you're right, but when you have a quiz tmr and a lab you tend to leave out the pretty stuff and just go with the flow haha,.. Thank you very much for your help! This will certainly help me when the mid terms come. I'm definitely sure I'll be able to solve these questions more with confidence now.